# Group By and Sort by Column in CMFCListCtrl

Tags: mfc

I have a derived  CMFCListCtrl which I can used group by and sort by fine via a contect menu.
However when group by is being used and I select a column to sort by (by clicking on the coloumn header) the arrow changes but the items are not sorted, I don't get my 'onsortby' message triggered either, any ideas?
I'm on XP is that the problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem when I was using Windows XP on my old computer.

Switching to a new computer with Windows 7 solved this issue. So I can cofirm that it's related to XP.

Answer (score 0):

I think XP may be the problem and that list control grouping requires Vista or higher. How do you have _WIN32_WINNT defined?

There is limited list control grouping available in XP: [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/CListCtrl_Grouping.aspx)

See [Windows Vista Control Enhancements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163384.aspx) from MSDN Magazine.

Comment: i can get the groupby to work fine in xp by only switching on collapsable group if equal or higher than vista,
if(mbIsVista == TRUE)
{
 grp.state  = LVGS_COLLAPSIBLE;
}

Do you know if there is a equalvalent 'method/way' to get the clicking on columns to work. I've tested in Vista and it works fine.
My _WIN32_WINNT is set to #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600 if that helps?